# Update all posts meta at the same time in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to run a function that will update all posts. My problem is that the function only runs when I visit that specific post (Only the specific post will be updated).

My function updates Facebook likes from the post source URL

```
function update_facebook_likes($content) {
    global $post;
    $url_path = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'url_source', TRUE);
    $data = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/?id='.$url_path.'&fields=share&access_token=****');
    $obj = json_decode($data);
    $like_na = $obj->{'share'};
    $like_no = $like_na->{'share_count'};
    update_post_meta($post->ID, 'fb_likes_count', $like_no); 
    }
add_action('wp', 'update_facebook_likes');


function display_fb_likes() {
    global $post;
    $fb_likes_count = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'fb_likes_count', true);
    echo $fb_likes_count;
}
```

Comment: What does *"for all posts in same time"* mean?

Comment: I want to update all my blog post. Now it is updating individually when I visit the blog post. But Facebook like are dynamic so I need to update for example a post from 4 days ago (even if nobody clicked on it)

Comment: Isn't there a way to get the number of likes via JavaScript so the actual page does not have to be updated constantly?

Comment: If nobody has visited the post, nobody knows it is not updated. When someone goes to the post, it gets updated with the latest info. What is wrong with that?

Comment: Ok I see, I am making a tool for myself where I can see what is the most popular posts from external posts. I need to put this data in the database in order to order the posts (automatically imported) by like counts (for example).

Comment: You are going to have to run this as an external process using cron or something similar.

Comment: Ok, so there is no way to update all posts at the same time when accessing the homepage of my "blog" ?

Comment: What kind of external process can I use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this foreach loop to update all posts. using `get_posts()` function 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
);
$posts_array = get_posts( $args );
foreach($posts_array as $post_array)
{
    update_post_meta($post_array->ID, 'fb_likes_count', true);
}
```

Comment: Only the first post of the page has the right amount

Comment: But this loop should work for all posts add example for your code

Comment: I think, it's not taking the good post_ID, maybe only for the first one ?

Comment: Ok, I know what is the problem. The problem is there : json_decode($data); Not working with the foreach

Comment: I hope this may help you, Good luck my friend :)

Comment: If I have so much record, the hosting will die with your block code